# logstash mysql general_logs CSV format

Tags: mysql, csv, logstash

I want to add the mysql general_log to the logstash. I have managed to make the mysql log in CSV format and with the CSV pattern there should be no easier thing to do. Here is my general_log entry:

```
"2015-08-15 11:52:57","mrr[mrr] @ localhost []",4703,0,"Query","SET NAMES utf8"
"2015-08-15 11:52:57","mrr[mrr] @ localhost []",4703,0,"Query","SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode"
"2015-08-15 11:52:57","mrr[mrr] @ localhost []",4703,0,"Query","SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'"
"2015-08-15 11:52:57","mrr[mrr] @ localhost []",4703,0,"Init DB","mrr"
```

and here is my logstash.conf:

```
 input {
        lumberjack {
                port => 5000
                type => "logs"
                ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash_forwarder.crt"
                ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash_forwarder.key"
        }
}
filter {
        if [type] == "nginx-access" {
                grok {
                        match => { 'message' => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:indent} %{NGUSER:agent} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|)\" %{NUMBER:answer} (?:%{NUMBER:byte}|-) (?:\"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-))\" (?:%{QS:referree}) %{QS:agent}' }
                }
                geoip {
                        source => "clientip"
                        target => "geoip"
                        database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
                        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
                        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
                }
                mutate {
                        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
                }
        }
        if [type] == "mysql-general" {
                csv {
                        columns => [ "@timestamp(6)", "user_host", "thready_id", "server_id", "ctype", "query" ]
                        separator => ","
                }
                grok {
                 match => { "user_host", "%{WORD:remoteuser}\[%{WORD:localuser}\] \@ %{IPORHOST:dbhost} \[(?:%{IPORHOST:qhost}|-)\]" }
                }
        }
}
output {
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch {
                host => "172.17.0.5"
                cluster => "z0z0.tk-1.5"
                flush_size => 2000
        }
}
```

however the user_host column has this format: 
`"mrr[mrr] @ localhost []"` and I would like to split it into at least two different values one for the user and the otherone for the host.

I have run this configuration on logstash and it ends up in _grokparsefailure due to the grok parse

when I am running the checktest option on the config file I am getting the following output:

```
Error: Expected one of #, => at line 36, column 26 (byte 1058) after filter {
    if [type] == "nginx-access" {
        grok {
            match => { 'message' => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:indent} %{NGUSER:agent} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|)\" %{NUMBER:answer} (?:%{NUMBER:byte}|-) (?:\"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-))\" (?:%{QS:referree}) %{QS:agent}' }
        }
        geoip {
            source => "clientip"
            target => "geoip"
            database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
            add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
            add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
        }
        mutate {
            convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
        }
    }
    if [type] == "mysql-general" {
        csv {
            columns => [ "@timestamp(6)", "user_host", "thready_id", "server_id", "ctype", "query" ]
            separator => ","
        }
        grok {
         match => { "user_host"
```

Can you give me an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Your input sets the type to 'logs' and your conditional is testing for 'mysql-general'.  You might want to fix that, or post the real config.

Comment: I have corrected the config file. Does this make sence now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The error was in fact in the grok patters since the first user and the last host was at some point emtpy the grok did failed in parsing so I had to add some brackets to accept also empty strings. The current logstash.conf looks like this:

```
input {
        lumberjack {
                port => 5000
                type => "logs"
                ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash_forwarder.crt"
                ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash_forwarder.key"
        }
}
filter {
        if [type] == "nginx-access" {
                grok {
                        match => { 'message' => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NGUSER:indent} %{NGUSER:agent} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|)\" %{NUMBER:answer} (?:%{NUMBER:byte}|-) (?:\"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-))\" (?:%{QS:referree}) %{QS:agent}' }
                }
                geoip {
                        source => "clientip"
                        target => "geoip"
                        database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
                        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
                        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
                }
                mutate {
                        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
                }
        }
        if [type] == "mysql-general" {
                csv {
                        columns => [ "@timestamp(6)", "user_host", "thready_id", "server_id", "ctype", "query" ]
                        separator => ","
                }
                grok {
                 match => { "user_host", "(?:%{WORD:remoteuser}|)\[%{WORD:localuser}\] \@ %{IPORHOST:dbhost} \[(?:%{IPORHOST:qhost}|)\]" }
                }
        }
}
output {
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch {
                host => "172.17.0.5"
                cluster => "clustername"
                flush_size => 2000
        }
}
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The csv{} filter is only parsing, um, comma-separated values.  If you'd like to parse fields of other formats, use grok{} on the user_host column after the csv{} filter has created it.

EDIT: to be more explicit.

Run the csv filter:

```
csv {
    columns => [ "@timestamp(6)", "user_host", "thready_id". "server_id", "ctype", "query" ]
    separator => ","
}
```

which should create you a field called "user_host".

You can then run this field through a grok filter, like this (untested) one:

```
grok {
    match => [ "user_host", "%{WORD:myUser}\[%{WORD}\] @ %{WORD:myHost} \[\]" ]
}
```

This will create two more fields for you: `myUser` and `myHost`.

Comment: I have configured the MySQL server to log in cab format that is why I have the input type as logs. And since the logstash-forwarder is sending the logs in csv to log stash I thought it is correct to set the filter as csv parser to create the different fields. However the field user_host has two values which I would like to take them to two separate fields and I don't really know how to do that. Maybe mutate split would be a good option.

Comment: Unless your 'type' is 'mysql-general', the csv filter won't be used.  As for further processing of a field, my answer suggested the use of grok{}.

Comment: I have the exact same setup for nginx only instead of using csv I am parsing the logs with grok and it works great

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, can I have two input types both being lumberjack with the same certificates?

Comment: You can have multiple inputs of same type, sure.  As long as the client(s) and the server(s) are using the right keys, they can be the same key.

Comment: The csv{} should work great, too.  Now, use a grok{} after the csv.

Comment: according to the information above can you please give me an example how to split and how to use grok on it? I don't really know if I should use grok on the whole string or only on the splitted part.